# animating padding top using jQuery hover and animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, I've looked over a few other questions on here about animating padding top and I've tried them all but nothing seems to be working for me so there's some kind of error I am missing. No error in the console.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.target-div').hover({
    $(this).animate({
      paddingTop: '+=5em'
    }, 500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      paddingTop: '0em'
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.target-div {
  background: #337ab7;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="target-div">One</div>
<div class="target-div">Two</div>
<div class="target-div">Three</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost had it. Notice the `function()` on the second line...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.target-div').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
      paddingTop: '+=5em'
    }, 500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      paddingTop: '0em'
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.target-div {
  background: #337ab7;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="target-div">One</div>
<div class="target-div">Two</div>
<div class="target-div">Three</div>
```

If you want to avoid the multiple animations when you hover in/out multiple times you need to add `.stop()` before triggering your animations...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.target-div').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
      paddingTop: '+=5em'
    }, 500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      paddingTop: '0em'
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.target-div {
  background: #337ab7;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target-div">One</div>
<div class="target-div">Two</div>
<div class="target-div">Three</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually do get an error in the console. It seems that you have a syntax error (you forgot `function()` in the first argument of `hover()`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.target-div').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      paddingTop: '+=5em'
    }, 500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      paddingTop: '0em'
    }, 500);
  });
});
```